# Make a JLabel in the position where mouse last was?

Tags: java, swing

I have a code that has a JLabel which follows the mouse. The JLabel says "exit" whenever the user exits the window, and stays at the last position the user was in. The problem is, the "exit" is only visible at when exiting the window from the top. This is because the JLabel is under the mouse. I want to make it so that the label moves down so I can see it if it exits up and move up if it exits down. I understand how to move it, but can we move it based on conditions? **It shows up in the window fine, I just need to position it on different sides of my mouse based on exit position.**
 Here is my code:

```
class giraffemousehandler extends MouseAdapter implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener { //MouseAdapter makes it so that you don't have to have all 7 implemented mouse listener methods

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        status.setBounds(e.getX(), e.getY(), 50, 60); //Makes JLabel follow mouse

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        status.setText("Entered");

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        status.setText("exited");
        // status.setBounds(e.getX(), e.getY(), 5, 6);

    }

}
}
```

Thank you so much for the time you are taking for reading this, I really appreciate the effort you are putting into helping a fellow programmer!

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: When you calculate the x/y position, you could check to see if those points are beyond the viewable area of the visible component and adjust the position accordingly AKA bounds checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class GiraffeMouseHandler extends MouseAdapter implements MouseMotionListener
{

    public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent event )
    {
        status.setText( "Entered" );
    }

    public void mouseExited( MouseEvent event )
    {
        status.setText( "Exited" ); 
    }

    public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent event )
    {
        //dimension is a reference of dimension of the main frame
        if( ( dimension.getHeight() - event.getY() ) < 65 )
            status.setBounds( event.getX(), (int)dimension.getHeight() - 65 , 50, 60 );
        else if( ( dimension.getWidth() - event.getX() ) < 50 )
            status.setBounds( (int)dimension.getWidth() - 50, event.getY(), 50, 60 );
        else
            status.setBounds( event.getX(), event.getY(), 50, 60 );         
    }

}
```